# Keyboard flickering when input text is focused inside a Webview

Tags: android, react-native, webview, keyboard

I have a component which renders a [WebView](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview) like this:

```
...
render(){
    <View style={[styles.container, style]}>
        <WebView url={url} />
    </View>
...
```

Inside the page that is loaded, there is a form containing some `input`(text and password). On Android 13+, sometimes(the bug does not occur always even with the same device), when one of the `input` is focused the Keyboard starts opening and closing without any action from the user.

Looking at the output of `adb logcat | grep 'focus'` all I can see is that these rows are printed over and over again in an infinite looop(even when the app is working normally).

```
03-08 17:44:50.111   914   914 D SurfaceFlinger: [input] inputWindowCommands.focusRequests size is 1
03-08 17:44:50.201  1217  3504 V WindowManager: Changing focus from null to Window{1339cc7 u0 com.myapp.testapp/com.myapp.MainActivity} displayId=0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.updateFocusedWindowLocked:595 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.updateFocusedWindowLocked:6803 com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.setResumedActivityUncheckLocked:5755 com.android.server.wm.TaskFragment.onActivityStateChanged:807
03-08 17:44:50.228   914   914 D SurfaceFlinger: [input] inputWindowCommands.focusRequests size is 1
03-08 17:44:50.292  1217  3460 V WindowManager: Changing focus from Window{1339cc7 u0 com.myapp.testapp/com.myapp.MainActivity} to null displayId=0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.updateFocusedWindowLocked:595 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.updateFocusedWindowLocked:6803 com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.setResumedActivityUncheckLocked:5755 com.android.server.wm.TaskFragment.onActivityStateChanged:807
03-08 17:44:50.303  1217  3504 E ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.myapp.testapp, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
03-08 17:44:50.311   914   914 D SurfaceFlinger: [input] inputWindowCommands.focusRequests size is 1
```

What could be the cause of the focus change loop?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by an external library used for requesting permissions on Android.

The library was using an outdated api that caused the app to go on a loop of states: background -> foreground -> background and so on. Everytime the state of the app changed the keyboard flickered.